# Continued Fraction Representation of sin(x)

Tags: taylor-expansion, fractions, continued-fractions

To provide context, the continued fraction in the form $\frac{a_0}{1-\frac{a_1}{1+a_1-\frac{a_2}{1+a_2-...}}}$ evaluated to the $n$th denominator equals $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\prod_{j=0}^{k}a_j$. If one wants to write $e^x$ as a continued fraction, you can take the Maclaurin series of it which is $1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n/n!$ and rewrite that as $1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x/i)$. Evaluating each $a_i$ to be in the form $x/i$, one can arrive at the continued series representation of $e^x$.

When I was trying to replicate this (rewriting other functions in the summation of products form), I had trouble with functions like log of x and trigonometric functions.

Can anybody help with getting $\sin{x}$ and $\cos{x}$ into the form $c+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\prod_{j=0}^{k}a_j$ where $c$ is either $0$ or $1$? The inverses of the function as well?

Comment: I thought a continued fraction has all 1's in the numerators. You are not talking about continued fractions, but rather generalized continued fraction forms (which are not unique). The question is therefore very ambiguous and has many answers.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I was unclear. I just want to see if there is a way of representing $\sin{x}$ in the form of the summation of products, like I did with $e^x$. Any form works, but the simpler the better.

Comment: You don't want to use the Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$? Its seems the process would be identical to your $e^x$ example.

Comment: I tried, but I can't manage to get that $x^{2n+1}$ part of the expansion in the form of a product.

Comment: You mean $\prod_{j=0}^{2k+1} \frac{x}{j}$? Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yeah, but that wouldn't be in the form $\sin{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\prod_{j=0}^{k}a_j$. It can also be $1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{k}a_j$ because that can also be rewritten into Euler's continued fraction.

Comment: I think we are arguing over syntax, putting a $2k+1$ in the numerator of a product means all the ones with $2k$ are zero. You could in theory write them out, but to say they are not there is not correct. For example, let $\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k!} x^k$, then $a_{2k}=0$ and $a_{2k+1}=(-1)^k$. It would be incorrect to say that $\sin(x)$ can't be written in standard series form, it is just half of the coefficients are zero and so we leave them off when we simplify the Maclaurin series.

Answer (score 1):

Lets write this up clearly, you want $\sin(x)$ to be written in a similar way to how you wrote $e^x$. This special form is essentially something like:
$$ 1 + \frac{x}{1} + \frac{x}{1}\frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{1}\frac{x}{2}\frac{x}{3} + \frac{x}{1}\frac{x}{2}\frac{x}{3}\frac{x}{4} + \frac{x}{1}\frac{x}{2}\frac{x}{3}\frac{x}{4}\frac{x}{5} + \cdots$$
$\sin(x)$ can also be written in this special way as well:
$$ 0 + \frac{x}{1} + 0\cdot 0 - \frac{x}{1}\frac{x}{2}\frac{x}{3} + 0\cdot 0\cdot 0 \cdot 0 + \frac{x}{1}\frac{x}{2}\frac{x}{3}\frac{x}{4}\frac{x}{5} + \cdots$$
half of the products you want to write are all zeros. Hope that helps.

Comment: Nope. The sum with zeros *doesn't* have the desired form. (But there's no need to introduce such terms; $x^2$ is not something to be afraid of.)